# Prove that an increasing sequence with a numerical limit is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, proof-explanation

Prove that an increasing sequence with a numerical limit is bounded.

I found the following proof referred to a convergent sequence, Can I use the same for this case (an increasing sequence)? I do not understand very well what is "$ C $" . What happens if the sequence is decreasing? Is there a better way to prove the theorem?

### Proof:

Let $s_n$ the sequence that converges to $l \in \mathbb{R}$. We take $\varepsilon =1 $ in the definition of limit, then exists a $n_o \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|s_n-l|<\varepsilon \ , \forall  \ n \geq n_o$. If $C=\max\{1,|s_1-l|,|s_2-l|\dots|s_{n_0-1}-l|\}$ then $|s_n-l|\leq C,$ it means $l-C\leq s_n\leq l+C $ so $s_n$ is bounded.

Comment: What is a numerical limit? Does it mean a finite limit?

Comment: @B.Mehta: I think so.

Comment: This proof is valid in general.

Comment: easier proof: all terms of the sequence are between $s_1$ and $l$, so the sequence is bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there can be a simpler proof.

Let me summarise the proof: by definition of the limit $\ell$, there exists an integer $n_0$ such that 
$$|s_n-\ell|  < 1\quad\forall n\ge n_0.$$
For the values of $n<n_0$ it may or may not be that $|s_n-\ell|\le 1$. But there's a finite number  of such $n$s anyway, so we may consider the greatest of all these numbers:
$$|s_0-\ell|,\, |s_1-\ell|, \dots,\,|s_{n_0-1}-\ell|,\, 1,$$
 which we denote $C$.

Now it is by construction that we have $|s_n-\ell|\le C$ for *any* $n$, since it is always no greater than one of the numbers in the list.

Comment: Thank you, so if I want to prove that an decreasing sequence with a  limit is bounded, can I use the same proof?

Comment: Absolutely. Note I nowhere used the monotonicity of the sequence: all convergent sequences are bounded.

Answer (score 1):

With $\epsilon=1, \exists m \in \Bbb N \; $,  such that

$$s_0\le s_n\le l+1$$ for $n>m.$

thus $\max (s_0,s_1,...s_m) =s_m$

and  $$\forall n\in\Bbb N \;\;
s_0\le s_n\le \max(s_m,l+1) .$$

Done.